# Microsoft Flow states that "This operation has no inputs." for an operation in my Custom API

Tags: swagger, microsoft-graph-api

I've created a swagger file that attempts to define the operations that I need from the Microsoft Graph API.

This API requires a couple of slightly complex data types to do things like creating users do I've therefore built these object and properties as a schema that provides a parameter 'parameters' in: body. See the snippets below.

I can register this Custom API in Flow but when I attempt to use an operation that has an in body parameter the action in Flow states that "This operation has no inputs."

```
/users:
post:
  tags:
    - User
  summary: Create User
  operationId: UserCreate
  description: >-
    Use this API to create a new User. The request body contains the user to
    create. At a minimum, you must specify the required properties for the
    user. You can optionally specify any other writable properties.
  parameters:
    - name: parameters
      in: body
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/UserCreateParameters'
      description: Parameters to create a user.
  responses:
    '201':
      description: >-
        Created. Indicates success. The new user is returned in the response
        body.
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/User'
    default:
      description: Error response
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/GraphError'
```

Definitions

```
PasswordProfile:
properties:
  password:
    type: string
    description: Password
  forceChangePasswordNextLogin:
    type: boolean
    description: Force change password on next login
required:
  - password
description: Contains the password profile associated with a user.

UserCreateParameters:
properties:
  accountEnabled:
    type: boolean
    description: Enable the account. If it is enabled then true else false.
  displayName:
    type: string
    description: User display name
  passwordProfile:
    $ref: '#/definitions/PasswordProfile'
  userPrincipalName:
    type: string
    description: >-
      The user principal name (someuser@contoso.com). It must contain one of
      the verified domains for the tenant.
  mailNickname:
    type: string
    description: The mail alias for the user
  immutableId:
    type: string
    description: >-
      Needs to be specified if you are using a federated domain for the
      user's userPrincipalName (UPN) property while creating a new user
      account. It is used to associate an on-premises Active Directory user
      account to their Azure AD user object.
required:
  - accountEnabled
  - displayName
  - passwordProfile
  - userPrincipalName
  - mailNickname
description: Request parameters for create a new work or school account user
```

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that the definitions, even thought they are valid Swagger and are validated by Flow, needs to have a type of 'object'.

As such, UserCreateParameters should be followed but type: object. E.g.

```
UserCreateParameters:
  type: object
  properties:
```

I've now included this at the start of every definition and all the fields are appearing as expected.